# How to store old data, and is this the correct way?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

Problem: Store a start_price with the date. The price can be changed multiple times and there should also be a reason stored for a price change.

I can't think of another way to do it than make a pricechange table?

```
CREATE TABLE price (
    start_price decimal(4,2) NOT NULL,
    price_date timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (start_price, price_date)
);

CREATE TABLE pricechange (
    start_price decimal(4,2) NOT NULL,
    new_price decimal(4,2) NOT NULL,
    price_date date NOT NULL,
    reason varchar(100),
    FOREIGN KEY (start_price, price_date)
    REFERENCES price(start_price, price_date)
);
```

I get a error in the pricechange table, also i dont know how to actually use sql to store the price from price into pricechange and store the new price as the price.

e.g price = 100. newprice = 50 reason: Too expensive. Should look like:

price table:
current_price: 50
price_date: timestamp of price creation

pricechange:
start_price: 100
new_price: 50
date: timestamp of pricechange
Reason: Too expensive

Comment: You need a separate column in `pricechange` for the change date, you can't use `price_date` for that since it's part of the FK

Comment: Minor point... your price columns use `decimal(4,2)` which is a range of -99.99 to +99.99 i.e. the price of 100 in your example is too large for the defined column to store!

Answer (score 0):

How about a single table with `price`, `effective_from` and `reason` columns. You can then use a view to show `current_prices` using a little cunning!

```
CREATE TABLE product_prices (
   product_id     int          NOT NULL
 , effective_date datetime     NOT NULL DEFAULT Current_Timestamp
 , price          decimal(4,2) NOT NULL
 , reason         varchar(400) NOT NULL
 , CONSTRAINT pk_product_prices PRIMARY KEY (product_id, effective_date)
 , CONSTRAINT fk_product_prices_products FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products (product_id)
);

CREATE VIEW current_product_prices
  AS
SELECT product_prices.product_id
     , product_prices.price
FROM   product_prices
 INNER
  JOIN (
        SELECT product_id
             , Max(effective_date) AS max_effectve_date
        FROM   product_prices
        WHERE  effective_date <= Current_Timestamp
        GROUP
            BY product_id
       ) AS current_price_date
    ON current_price_date.product_id = product_prices.product_id
   AND current_price_date.max_effectve_date = product_prices.effective_date
;
```

This is air-code (i.e. conceptual and un-tested) as I'm not somewhere I can run MySQL at the mo.

... but it should be illustrative (enough)!

Comment: @GordonLinoff - in what way? Just tested it on a MySQL instance now and it seems very merry...

Comment: . . That's odd.  Subqueries are not usually allowed in the `from` clause for views.  It can be a real pain.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the price change table because that is what you really need:

```
create table price_changes (
    price_change_id int auto_increment primary key,
    start_price decimal(4,2) NOT NULL,
    new_price decimal(4,2) NOT NULL,
    price_date date NOT NULL,
    reason varchar(100)
);
```

You would just insert new prices into this table.

Then you can maintain a table `current_prices` using a trigger.  Or, if you prefer, a view:

```
create view price_date, current_price as
    select pc.new_price as price
    from price_changes pc
    order by change_date desc
    limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the other Answers (so far).  I suspect that your example is simplified and/or will become more complex as time goes on.  Hence, the queries will get messy and/or slow.

I suggest 2 tables.  Think of one as "current" and one as "history".  Whenever a price change happens, `history` gets `INSERTed` into and `current` gets updated.  I would do those two steps in app code *or* a Stored Proc *or* with the aid of a `TRIGGER`.

Design the columns of each table based on what queries will be applied to each.  Do not think about `FOREIGN KEYs` until you find a need for them.  Keep in mind that the two tables will perhaps never be used in the same query.